# How to create a shortcut for eclipse

Tags: linux-mint, eclipse, desktop-shortcuts

Today i downloaded the latest installer(`eclipse-inst-linux64.tar.gz`) of eclipse from the official website and i installed in my system. now i want to create a shortcut to launch the program. how can i do that ? if i double click on the eclipse file which is selected as the screenshot i am able to launch the program, someone help me to create a shortcut [image: see the picture]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can create a .desktop file:

```
$ cd Desktop
$ touch eclipse.desktop
```

Open it with your favorite text editor (gedit, for example):

```
$ gedit eclipse.desktop
```

Add this to that file:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
Name=Name of your application
Icon=/path/to/icon
Exec=/path/to/application
```

Finally, make it executable:

```
$ chmod u+x eclipse.desktop
```

Final result should be something like:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

**You can create an application launcher in your panel:**

1- Right click on your panel

2- Choose add to panel

3- Custom application Launcher

4- Then, add the path of the executable as a command and specify the icon and other metadata

The steps may differ slightly on your desktop environment but the idea is the same.

---

**If you want an actual link on desktop or somewhere else:**

1- Right click on the executable

2- make link (or similar option)

3- And rename/move the link as you like

or using the command line

```
ln -s YOUR_EXECUTABLE_PATH YOUR_LINK_PATH
```

---

**Or you can create a desktop entry to add a launcher to your menu and here's how:**
https://community.linuxmint.com/tutorial/view/1504